# We want an application outside domain accessible for users using domain credentials without entering user name and password

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-core-6.0

Our application is deployed outside domain and we want the same application accessible for users inside domain using domain credentials without entering user name and password.  Can anyone guide me  to achieve this goal

Trying to use Azure Active Directory authentication to achieve this but not sure about azure agent installation. Will it be able to integrate properly with less efforts on present on premise AD (up to now not having idea how it's maintained in client's domain).

Our application is is using .NET 6.0.

As doing this 1st time can anyone guide me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this, but I can give you some reference and direction.

If you have a different domain internally and externally, you can use `KCD` for single sign-on. If you do not need single sign-on, you can also refer to the working logic of `KCD` to achieve your current cross-domain access requirements. You can refer to [this article](https://www.jgspiers.com/azure-application-proxy/) to better understand Azure AD Application Proxy and its principle.

On another level (if you use `Azure Active Directory`) what you really need is to set up `Azure Active Directory` authentication, you need to choose a correct authentication method. Please refer to [Setting Azure Active Directory authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#setting-azure-active-directory-authentication)  for more details.

If you want to maintain it, please refer to [Manage Different Domains in Active Directory Administrative Center](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/group-managed-service-accounts/manage-different-domains-in-active-directory-administrative-center). Your domain A and domain B should also be in one-way trust mode, so I think this document will help you a lot.

In addition, browser security usually prevents a web page from making AJAX requests to another domain. This restriction is called the same-origin policy, and prevents a malicious site from reading sensitive data from another site. However, sometimes you might want to let other sites call your web API. CORS is a W3C standard that lets a server relax the same-origin policy and allow some cross-origin requests while rejecting others. Please refer to [Understand and solve Azure Active Directory Application Proxy CORS issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-understand-cors-issues) for more details.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Trying to solve this in same direction. It will be really nice if here is anyone who actually did this before and guide me the same way..